# Convert hour:minute:second (HH:MM:SS) string to proper time class

Tags: r, time

In the following data frame the 'time' column is `character` in the format `hour:minute:second`

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
time <- c("00:00:01", "01:02:00", "09:30:01", "14:15:25")
df <- data.frame(id, time)
```

How can I convert 'time' column to a dedicated time class, so that I can perform arithmetic calculations on it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the function `chron` in package `chron`:

```
time<-c("00:00:01", "01:02:00", "09:30:01", "14:15:25")

library(chron)
x <- chron(times=time)

x
[1] 00:00:01 01:02:00 09:30:01 14:15:25
```

Do some useful things, like calculating the difference between successive elements:

```
diff(x)
[1] 01:01:59 08:28:01 04:45:24
```

---

`chron` objects store the values internally as a fraction of seconds per day. Thus 1 second is equivalent to `1/(60*60*24)`, or `1/86400`, i.e. `1.157407e-05`.

So, to add times, one simple option is this:

```
x + 1/86400
[1] 00:00:02 01:02:01 09:30:02 14:15:26
```

Comment: And, what if I have the time in a 12 hour format? Example : `time<-c("01:00:01 am", "01:02:00 pm", "09:30:01 am", "02:15:25 pm")` . The `chron()`does not handle that. So, is there any other function for it?

Comment: Is there a way to use it with HH:MM format? ```chron(times=time, format=c(times="h:m"))``` does not work...

Answer (score 30):

Using base R you could convert it to an object of class `POSIXct`, but this does add a date to the time:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
time<-c("00:00:01","01:02:00","09:30:01","14:15:25")
df<-data.frame(id,time,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2012-08-20 00:00:01 CEST" "2012-08-20 01:02:00 CEST"
[3] "2012-08-20 09:30:01 CEST" "2012-08-20 14:15:25 CEST"
```

But that does allow you to perform arithmetic calculations on them.

Comment: How would you find a subset based on the hh:mm:ss? I don't think subset `(df, df$time >"2012-08-20 00:00:01 CEST" | df$time <"2012-08-20 14:15:25 CEST"` works.

Comment: What if the time is in 12 hour format, using AM/PM?

Comment: @Rodrigo (but obviously a bit late) Just use the input formatting codes that you will find on the `?strptime` page. Those format specifications can also be used with `as.POSIXct`

Answer (score 8):

Another possible alternative could be:

```
time <- c("00:00:01","01:02:00","09:30:01","14:15:25")
converted.time <- as.difftime(time, units = "mins") #"difftime" class
secss <- as.numeric(converted.time, units = "secs")
hourss <- as.numeric(converted.time, units = "hours")
dayss <- as.numeric(converted.time, units="days")
```

Or even:

```
w <- strptime(x = time, format = "%H:%M:%S") #"POSIXlt" "POSIXt" class
```

Comment: `as.difftime` converts to numeric and does not add a date, what was undesired: `as.difftime("15:31:29",format="%H:%M:%S",unit='hours')`

Answer (score 7):

Using the `ITime` class in `data.table` package:

> `ITime` is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day.

```
library(data.table)
(it <- as.ITime(time))
# [1] "00:00:01" "01:02:00" "09:30:01" "14:15:25"

it + 10
# [1] "00:00:11" "01:02:10" "09:30:11" "14:15:35"


diff(it)
# [1] "01:01:59" "08:28:01" "04:45:24"
```

Comment: Why does it not automatically read HH:mm:ss as `ITime` with `fread`?

Answer (score 7):

`lubridate` allows good flexibility on the time format :

```r
library(lubridate)

time_hms_1<-c("00:00:01", "01:02:00", "09:30:01", "14:15:25")
hms(time_hms_1)
#> [1] "1S"          "1H 2M 0S"    "9H 30M 1S"   "14H 15M 25S"


time_hms_2<-c("0:00:01", "1:02:00", "9:30:01", "14:15:25")
hms(time_hms_2)
#> [1] "1S"          "1H 2M 0S"    "9H 30M 1S"   "14H 15M 25S"

time_hm_1<-c("00:00", "01:02", "09:30", "14:15")
hm(time_hm_1)
#> [1] "0S"         "1H 2M 0S"   "9H 30M 0S"  "14H 15M 0S"

time_hm_2<-c("0:00", "1:02", "9:30", "14:15")
hm(time_hm_2)
#> [1] "0S"         "1H 2M 0S"   "9H 30M 0S"  "14H 15M 0S"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Yet another alternative using the [`hms`](https://github.com/tidyverse/hms) package.

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
time <- c("00:00:01", "01:02:00", "09:30:01", "14:15:25")
df <- data.frame(id, time, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Convert column `time` to class `hms`

```
# install.packages("hms")
library(hms)
df$time <- as.hms(df$time)
```

Perform arithmetic calculations

```
diff(df$time)
#01:01:59
#08:28:01
#04:45:24
```