# Error while aggregating factor variable- argument is not numeric or logical

Tags: r, aggregate

Below is the `str` of my data set.

```
'data.frame':   9995 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Count           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Gates    : Factor w/ 5 levels "B6","B9","I1",..: 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Entry_Date           : Date, format: "0006-10-20" "0006-10-20" "0006-10-20" ...
 $ Entry_Time           : Factor w/ 950 levels "00:01:00","00:04:00",..: 347 366 450 550 563 700 701 350 460 506 ...
 $ Exit_Date          : Date, format: "0006-10-20" "0006-10-20" "0006-10-20" ...
 $ Exit_Time          : Factor w/ 1012 levels "00:00:00","00:01:00",..: 618 556 637 694 770 936 948 590 640 655 ...
 $ Type_of_entry    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Manual","Pass",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ weekday     : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 6 6 6 ...
 $ Ticket.Loss: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Duration  : Factor w/ 501 levels "00:01:00","00:02:00",..: 223 142 139 96 159 188 199 192 132 101 ...
```

I am using below function:

```
W <- aggregate(Duration ~ Gates, data=parking, FUN=mean)
```

But getting below error:

> Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @Priyanka The levels of 'Duration' seems to be `character` (possibly time).  In that case, do you want the `mean` time.

Answer (score 2):

`Duration` is a factor of strings that look like time durations, "00:01:00", etc.

The `chron` package works with character strings such as this.

```
library(chron)
aggregate(chron(times=Duration) ~ Gates, data=parking, FUN=mean)
```

This will give the average time for each level in `Gates`.

See also [convert character to time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034424/convert-character-to-time-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

If the OP's dataset is infact time column, we can use `as.POSIXct` to convert it to 'DateTime' class

```
parking$Duration <- as.POSIXct(parking$Duration, format = "%H:%M:%S")
transform(aggregate(Duration ~ Gates, data = parking, FUN = mean), 
                               Duration = sub("\\S+\\s+", "", Duration))
#  Gates Duration
#1    B6 11:08:34
#2    B9 11:07:31
#3    I1 11:07:10
```

NOTE: No external packages used.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
parking <- data.frame(Gates = sample(c("B6", "B9", "I1"), 20, replace=TRUE),
  Duration = format(seq(Sys.time(), length.out=20, by = "1 min") , "%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate

Comment: @Priyanka Corrected the output.  Please check now.