# All values turning to NA while converting character to time type variable in R

Tags: r

I tried to convert a column containing time details from characters to a time type variable. The code works but converts all the characters into NA. The values in the column before the code looks like '06:34:10'

The code I am running is similar to this:

`df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format = "%H-%M-%S")`

I want it to be a time variable so I can conduct analyses by grouping the different times an event occurred.

Comment: did you look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034424/convert-character-to-time-in-r

Comment: You have `:` in the data and `-` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

: instead to -

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
df$time <- strptime(df$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```