# How to subtract time in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have two columns 1) Start.Time 2) End.Time .

The data in both column is in chr format and " 00:00:00 ".

How could I get a column that has the duration? (End.Time. - Start.Time)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Convert them to a date-time class like `POSIXct` and then subtraction will work just fine. See [a couple options here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12034424/903061).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also convert to `ITime` with `data.table` and get the difference

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration := as.ITime(t1) - as.ITime(t2)]
```

-output

```
df
#        t1       t2 duration
#1: 12:24:13 10:46:34 01:37:39
#2: 10:04:39 09:43:23 00:21:16
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(t1 = c("12:24:13", "10:04:39"), t2 = c("10:46:34", "09:43:23"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `chron` package

```
transform(
  df,
  duration = chron(times = t1) - chron(times = t2)
)
```

such that

```
        t1       t2 duration
1 12:24:13 10:46:34 01:37:39
2 10:04:39 09:43:23 00:21:16
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(t1 = c("12:24:13", "10:04:39"), t2 = c("10:46:34", "09:43:23"))
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I have 700 observations in each column, so how could I convert the whole column using hms()

Comment: @roosadahal I updated my answer so it may work on your data frame

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
t1 <- c('12:24:13','10:04:39')
t2 <- c('10:46:34','09:43:23')

unclass(as.POSIXct(t1,format="%H:%M:%S")) - unclass(as.POSIXct(t2,format="%H:%M:%S"))
[1] 5859 1276
attr(,"tzone")
```

POSIXct is number of seconds since epoch, which is 1970-01-01. In above example, the output is difference between times in seconds.