# Is there a way of converting four-digit numbers to time values in r?

Tags: r

When I try using as.POSIXlt or strptime I keep getting a single value of 'NA' as a result.

What I need to do is transform 3 and 4 digit numbers e.g. 2300 or 115 to 23:00 or 01:15 respectively, but I simply cannot get any code to work.

Basically, this data fame of outputs:

```
Time
1   2345
2   2300
3   2130
4   2400
5    115
6   2330
7    100
8   2300
9   1530
10   130
11   100
12   215
13  2245
14   145
15  2330
16  2400
17  2300
18  2230
19  2130
20    30
```

should look like this:

```
Time
    1   23:45
    2   23:00
    3   21:30
    4   24:00
    5   01:15
    6   23:30
    7   01:00
    8   23:00
    9   15:30
    10  01:30
    11  01:00
    12  02:15
    13  22:45
    14  01:45
    15  23:30
    16  24:00
    17  23:00
    18  22:30
    19  21:30
    20  00:30
```

Comment: Is this a question about *formatting* or type *conversion*? In other words, do you simple want to reformat "2345" as "23:45"? Or do you need to convert a `character` vector into an e.g. `POSIXct` vector.

Comment: @Michael To convert your data to a dedicated time class, see [Convert hour:minute:second (HH:MM:SS) string to proper time class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034424/convert-hourminutesecond-hhmmss-string-to-proper-time-class)

Comment: Please do not vandalise your own post when it has received an answer - there's a reason why you cannot delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following solution. However this is actually producing a character vector:

```
gsub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", sprintf("%04d", df$Time)) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames("Time") |>
  head()

   Time
1 23:45
2 23:00
3 21:30
4 24:00
5 01:15
6 23:30
```

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for? It's just character vector. I don't think you could turn a numeric into time without date! and with regard to your question could you elaborate more?

Comment: I am so sorry I just don't understand your point. Could you please put it here and I will take a look at it asap. Or possibly ask a new question.